# Run a method every X seconds

Tags: java, timer

I'm creating a text based game in Java as my first official program on my own.
It's survival game with Hunger, Thirst, and Body Temperature variables.

Lets say I want hunger and thirst to decrease once every 5 seconds or so.
Only thing I can get to work at the moment is this.
This deceases the numbers for sure, but it goes from 100 to 0 in 2 seconds.

```
public void run(){
  while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
    }
private void tick(){
  Health.playerHealth.tick();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

public static Health playerHealth = new Health();

private static int hunger = 100;
private static int thirst = 100;
private static double bodyTemperature = 98.6;

public void tick(){
    depleteHunger();
    depleteThirst();
    depleteBodyTemperature();
}

public void depleteHunger(){
    hunger--;

}

public void depleteThirst(){
    thirst--;
}
```

I've tried this timer as well, but it only waits 5 seconds i put in *THEN* decreases from 100 to 0 instantly

```
private void tick(){

Timer t = new Timer();
  t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      depleteHunger();
      depleteThirst();
      depleteBodyTemperature();
    }
  }, 0, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can look at timer's `scheduleAtFixedRate`:

**Sample example:**

```
Timer timerObj = new Timer(true);
timerObj.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, interval));
```

This method basically does what you wish to achieve: execute a task at specific intervals.
You need to initialized the `TimerTask` object by overriding the `run()` method and putting your logic inside that though (as you have mentioned in your code as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
final int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 20;
final int TICK_TIME = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;

while (running) {
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // some actions
    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long diff = endTime - startTime;

    if (diff < TICK_TIME) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TICK_TIME - diff);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution.

```
public class HealthStatsTimer extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
    Health.playerHealth.depleteHunger();
    Health.playerHealth.depleteThirst();
    Health.playerHealth.depleteBodyTemperature();
  }
}
//////////////////////
public static void main(String[] args){
  new Stranded();

  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new HealthStatsTimer(), 5000, 5000);
}
```